# tailwindcss hidden class in table header / row

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to create a responsive table layout in tailwindcss where certain columns will be hidden if the display size is mobile.

I'm adding `hidden sm:inline-block` to the `th` and `td` values that I want hidden, but the `inline-block` display breaks the normal flow of the table. I've tried `block`, `flex`, `inline-flex`, etc. but they all mess with the layout of the header and columns when viewed at the larger screen sizes.

What is the "normal" display for these elements that should be used in the breakpoint directive instead of `inline-flex`?

Here's a look at the code, by removing the `hidden sm:inline-block` you can see what *should* be displayed vs. what is displayed.
https://play.tailwindcss.com/jyMaE0MVWx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default is `display: table-cell` so setting `sm:table-cell` should do the trick. Here is a remix of your play https://play.tailwindcss.com/g7PJ6ETsX5

Edit: You can always find the default display property for an element in the inspector inside the computed properties tab.